# Pass a variable from razor to javascript and display it

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I have a variable

```
var result = client.DownloadString(query);
```

in mvc 4 rzaor. By hovering it in the debugging process, it likes the image below
[image: result]

What I want is to display it, so I return it to javascript with the code:

```
function myFunction() {
        $('#response').text('@(Url.Action("result"))');
    }
```

**EDIT:**

```
<div id="response"></div>
@{
   var strSearch = "test";
   var options = "include-passage-references=true";
   var client = new WebClient();
   var query = string.Format("http://www.xxx.org/v2/rest/passageQuery?key={0}&passage={1}&options={2}", "IP", Server.UrlEncode(strSearch), options);
   var result = client.DownloadString(query);
 }
```

However nothing found.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use the ViewBag for that.

On C#:

```
ViewBag.result = client.DownloadString(query);
```

On HTML:

```
function myFunction() {
        $('response').text('@ViewBag.result');
}
```

Comment: client.DownloadString(query); was generated in a view, can we use ViewBag? I want to pass it from a view to js.

Comment: I got a stranger error :SCRIPT1015: Unterminated string constant.

Comment: Ok, probably the result of client.DownloadString contains unescaped quotes ('). You have to escape them before sending the content to JS.

Comment: Considering that DownloadString returns a string, try this: ViewBag.result = client.DownloadString(query).Replace("'", "\'");